# Why is my template html file not using bootsrap css?

Tags: django

I'm Sreenesh, a beginner in Django web framework.
I've been facing some problems while doing a project.
this is my
[OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPBr2.png) of my django website which is not what i expected it to be.
this is my
[HTML CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LuZu.png) from this I think you can say output is not the desired one.
command prompt throws me these 2 errors [CMD PROMPT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAixi.png) and I'm unable to fix these problems on my own as I'm a self learner.this is my [bootstrap files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAkIX.png) directory as you can see the path I specified in link tag in my html code is right. this is my [Settings.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffgfb.png) and [Url.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfHVp.png). Could anyone help me where i am doing wrong and how to fix these problems so I can get ahead with my project and learn some valuable lessons. Thank you everyone.

Update: this is my folder [tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mI62R.png) for those who need it for some verifications.

Comment: Can you add a snapshot of your project tree. Just to check if all files are in the correct place.

Comment: @Rvector i have added snapshot of my project tree plz take a look and suggest me a solution if you can. thank you

Comment: I added a new answer, another best way to add bootstrap to Django project via **[CDN](https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you are facing some trouble wile using bootstrap in local then use CDN**

in your base `html` file :
**Into the `<head>` tag**

```
<!-- Boostrap css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

**Just before closing the body tag**

```
<!-- jQuery and Bootstrap js -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Try it and let us know the result

Comment: thanks it worked, I got my desired output. but it got favicon 404 error. In which cases should I use CDN of bootstrap?

Comment: For the `favicon` issue, it is normal and is only a warning. But if you want to add a `favicon` to Django try [this tutorial](https://realfavicongenerator.net/). For the CDN, it's good because it'll be easy to upgrade the `Bootstrap` version, since you have to change only the link. Also, plz mark the answer as it resolve your issue.

Comment: thank you, I have marked your answer. I'm new to stackoverflow thats why didnt knew to mark your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a 404 error (does not exist) when it tries to load bootstrap.min.css. So, it's not in the folder specified by

```
{% static css/css/bootstrap.min.css %}
```

(or possibly, there's a file protection problem). Anyway, I think that translates to $BASE_DIR/static/css/css/bootstrap.min.css (using Linux notation, I don't do Windows).

Check that the file is there? And to debug in case I'm wrong, you can get the actual path it's looking for by using the same template tag to generate visible HTML content, or an HTML comment that you can see with your browser view page source

```
<!-- trying to load bootstrap from {% static css/css/bootstrap.min.css %} -->
```

Comment: its there, I tried like you said.  C:\Users\DELL 3800\projec\ts\projects\static\css\css\bootstrap.min.css this path is opening the the bootstrap file, idk why django failing to open the file